# Google Cloud Endpoints Framework - EndpointServlet ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, appengine-gradle-plugin

I'm migrating from Google Cloud Endpoints(v1) to Google Cloud Endpoints Framework(v2).  I'm using Java standard environment on App Engine.  Also using the [App Engine gradle plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin) and the [Gradle plugin for appengine and endpoints framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin).

My project will compile and deploy, however it will deploy to what appears to be a staging version (version name is date + time despite being set in `appengine-web.xml`).

Then once hitting the endpoint I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointServlet
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-4c1b66acdf400e18(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)

javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointServlet
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
```

I've followed the migration guides and updated my `web.xml` and `appengine-web.xml` to reflect the new classes.  Any help would be great!

Comment: Please post your gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the exception you pasted, it seems like you made a typo in your `web.xml`: you wrote `com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointServlet` instead of `com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet`.